# Selecting UserID's Database Entry

Tags: php, mysql, sql, vbulletin

I am using vBulletin forum software 3.8 in which there are multiple ways to pull the current users userid:

```
$vbulletin->GPC['userid']
$vbulletin->userinfo['userid']
$bbuserinfo['userid']
```

All of which return the same value, in my case `1`

I have created a table to store login information which stores the users ID like so:

```
INSERT INTO logins (userid, phpdate)
VALUES (" . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . ", " . TIMENOW . ")
```

Using Navicat I can run a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM logins
WHERE userid = 1
ORDER BY phpdate ASC
LIMIT 5
```

This gives me the correct results, so I then converted this query to vBulletin format changing the `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE userid = $vbulletin->userinfo['userid']
```

Doing this is throwing an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'userid' (T_STRING), expecting ')'
```

I have tried wrapping the variable in `intval($var)` `IN ($var)` but I can't seem to get any variation of this to work, I have even tried to escape the `'` `$vbulletin->userinfo[\'userid\']`.

So question time: How can I select the userid within my query?

I am on `PHP 7.4`

To overcome this for now I am using an if condition in my while loop

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $row['phpdate'] =    vbdate( $vbulletin->options['dateformat'], $row['phpdate'], true );
    if ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] == $row['userid']){
        ...
    }
}
```

Although this is not allowing me to limit the results per userid, and I had other plans if I can get the SQL statement to function.

I am constantly messing with this waiting some help the current method I have is:

```
$result = $db->query('
SELECT *
FROM logins
WHERE userid = ' . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . '
ORDER BY phpdate ASC
LIMIT 5
');
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $row['phpdate'] =   vbdate( $vbulletin->options['dateformat'], $row['phpdate'], true );

     if ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] == $row['userid']){
      $drcpi_tbl_gutz .= '
        <li><ul class="device">
        <li class="icon">';
          $drcpi_tbl_gutz .= '<i class="fal fa-question-square fa-fw"></i>';
       $drcpi_tbl_gutz .= '</li>
        <li class="browser">' . $row['os'] . ' <small>(' . $row['browser'] . ')</small></li><li class="logindate time">' . $row['phpdate'] . '</li>
        <li class="ip-address">' . $row['ipaddress'] . ' <a class="location-lookup" title="Get approximate location of this IP address." href="https://www.iplocation.net/?query=' . $row['ipaddress'] . '"><i class="fal fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li></ul></li>
     ';
      }
    }
    $result->free();
```

Which is throwing an invalid SQL error:

```
WHERE userid = ' . Array['userid'] . '
```

Comment: `WHERE userid = $vbulletin->userinfo['userid']` ...show this in context of the whole line, please. P.S. You should be using prepared statements and parameterised queries anyway, so this issue should not arise - never concatenate variable values directly into your SQL.

Comment: The whole line would be `SELECT * FROM logins WHERE userid = $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] ORDER BY phpdate ASC LIMIT 5` as for the variable in the query, are you meaning I should do something like `$var = $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'];` then use `$var` in the query?

Comment: `as for the variable in the query, are you meaning I should do something like $var = $vbulletin->userinfo['userid']; then use $var in the query?`...no that would have exactly the same issue. What database library are you using to connect to the database? Mysqli? Or PDO? Or something else? They all have their own particular syntax for using prepared statements and parameters, so you need to check documentation and tutorials for the specific library. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using popular PHP libraries

Comment: `SELECT * FROM logins WHERE userid = $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] ORDER BY phpdate ASC LIMIT 5`...that must be within a PHP string in your application, though? Again, can you show the _whole_ line of PHP code please. (I am guessing you've got an issue with quote marks within an already single-quoted string, or something like that. But anyway, the issue goes away entirely if you use parameters properly - it doesn't just solve the SQL injection problem, it solves all sorts of potential syntax problems too).

Comment: `As requested, my entire code block `....no that's not what I requested.

Comment: I posted the way I have it set up live currently, without selecting userid.  Sorry allow me a moment to adjust.  That is what you wanted though right?

Comment: And the block you've shown doesn't appear to include the SQL you're complaining about, either.

Comment: It's simple. Please show the whole line of PHP code which includes the text `SELECT * FROM logins WHERE userid = $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] ORDER BY phpdate ASC LIMIT 5`. The code you've shown does not include that.

Comment: updated original post

Comment: `WHERE userid = ' . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . '` isn't the same as `WHERE userid = $vbulletin->userinfo['userid']` which is what you stated originally. ``WHERE userid = ' . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . '`` won't cause the PHP syntax error. So I can only assume, from this, that your problem is solved? (However it should still be parameterised anyway, as I advised earlier.)

Comment: I am playing around with this trying to figure it out, I have many versions of it.  No it is not resolved, as for even the method I posted is still throwing an error

Comment: `WHERE userid = $vbulletin->userinfo['userid']` causes the PHP syntax error you mentioned. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45c81158e3d6a1ed8968e50656f65ed5d391a900 . But `WHERE userid = ' . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . '` **doesn't** cause that error. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8a4df35b878db3d43107b46ef2b6034100d33576 (those other errors you see when you run the demo are runtime errors, but they would not occur if there was still a syntax error).  So if it's causing you a **different** error now, you need to tell us what that error is.

Comment: the error is an SQL error in the WHERE clause `WHERE userid = ' . Array['userid'] . '` it is returning an array, although in other vBulletin products this is the exact method used, so I'm not sure why it is returning as an array and not a userid #, I'm going to do some digging and update.

Comment: Ok yes it seems maybe `$vbulletin->userinfo['userid']` returns an array for some reason. I don't know the vbulletin product specifically so I can't help you with why it's doing that.

Comment: figured it out, don't know why or how exactly, just followed suit with another product.  adding answer now

Answer (score 1):

After multiple attempts at figuring this out I decided to look at some other vBulletin products.  Following suit with them I wrote my query how they appeared in other products.

My end result was:

```
$result = $db->query("
SELECT *
FROM logins
WHERE userid='".$vbulletin->userinfo['userid']."'
");
```

The difference being the types of quotes, and where they were placed.

If anyone would care to elaborate on why this solution works when the method provided in the original post does not, I would appreciate the feedback.  All I know is this way works and that way did not.

Comment: In SQL, single quotes around a variable allow you to use a string (non-numeric) value in the query. Presumably your IDs are not numeric. P.S. As I've mentioned above, parameterising your queries correctly would have allowed you to avoid this issue entirely (as the process of including the variable value correctly into the query is taken care of automatically by the database engine).